# Classification of English Words Based on Class [Noun, Verb, Adjective, Preposition, etc]

Tags: natural-language-processing

```
def Interpretation_be(sentence):

     be = ( 'be', 'been', 'is', 'was', 'are', 'were' )
     place = ('there', 'here')
     gender_identity = ('he', 'she')
     indicator =('it', 'that', 'this', 'these', 'those')
     exist =('exist')
     equal=('equal')
     condition=('condition', 'status', 'quality', 'state', 'situation' 'circumstance') 
     number =('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
     consequence=('consequence', 'result')
     to = ('to') 


     if sentence.split()[1] in be:
          if sentence.split()[0] in place:
               print(sentence.replace(sentence.split()[1],'exists'))
          if sentence.split()[0] in gender_identity:
               print(sentence.replace(sentence.split()[1],'equal to'))
          if sentence.split()[0] in indicator:
               print(sentence.replace(sentence.split()[1],'equal to'))

     if sentence.split()[1] in exist:
           if sentence.split()[0] in place:
               print(sentence.replace(sentence.split()[1],'is'))

     if sentence.split()[1] in equal:
          if sentence.split()[0] in condition:
                  print(sentence.replace(sentence.split()[1],'is'))
          if sentence.split()[0] in number:
                  print(sentence.replace(sentence.split()[1],'is'))
          if sentence.split()[0] in consequence:
                  print(sentence.replace(sentence.split()[1],'is'))

     if sentence.split()[2] in to:
           print(sentence.replace(sentence.split()[2],'toward'))
           ##need to discern between preoposition to and infinitive to##

##result_check##
Interpretation_be('i have been to Spain')
Interpretation_be('there was a cat')
Interpretation_be('there is a woman')
Interpretation_be('he is a boy')
Interpretation_be('it is a cat')
Interpretation_be('there exist a hat')
Interpretation_be('situation equal to bad')
Interpretation_be('1 equal one')
Interpretation_be('consequence eqaul bad')
```

I am trying to make up English rephraser as a most basic start of natural language processing.

While building up like above code, I had wanted to get some already-classified text data which criteria of classification is word-class, such as Noun, Verb, Preposition etc.

Any good text data that I can obtain?

Please let me know.